# Why is my JS code that only runs a for loop have an error?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to draw ellipses in the line `y=0`. I am running this in p5js. This is my code:

```js
function setup() { // Sets up background
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(100);
  clear();
}

function draw() {
  for (int x = 0 x < 1000, x++;) {
    ellipse(x, 0, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you need to fix your `for` loop. Instead of `for(int x=0 x<1000, x++ ;){` it should be `for(int x=0; x<1000; x++ ;){`

Comment: Your `for` loop is full of syntax errors.  Take another look at the documentation and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forget some ';' in your for

Your is like that : `for(int x=0 x<1000, x++ ;){`

You must write it like that : `for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++){`

You can use documentation for more informations : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration